# Maps center and zoom on markers after ajax/json request

Tags: javascript, maps

i am making a google maps view with multiple markers.
these markers are placed based on a ajax request wich is activated everytime there is changed a filter setting (like show only hotels)

i want to change the zoom and center everytime the new markers are added to the bounds of the markers. but for some reason it wont work the right way.
it seems like the removed markers are still recognised.

i hope someone can help me:)

this is the javascript code:

```
var locations = [];
            $.each( data.result, function( key, item ) {
                locations.push([item.Title,item.Latitude,item.Longitude]);
            });
            console.log(locations);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

            //clear marks
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }

            //set marks
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                }));
            }

            //set the center
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            console.log(bounds);
            for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
                bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
            }
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

this is one of the keys in the locations array on line 5

```
0: "Nationaal Zwemcentrum de Tongelreep"
1: "51.4113463"
2: "5.4760268"
```

Comment: in case of more then one marker what you want to do which marker you want at the center with zoom?

Comment: I want to zoom and center so all the markers are visible

this piece of code works, but just once.

Comment: after your ajax request all the data is going away from the map?

Comment: No, its sort of a filter. and every time you change a filter value this ajax request is called. and then first it removes all the marks (under //clear marks) and then it adds new marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one in combination with the answer of cracker did the trick

http://blog.shamess.info/2009/09/29/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-maps-api-v3/

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Ajax Call EVevnt

```
var markers = [];//Top of all to access in whole javascript

$.each( data.result, function( key, item ) {
   markers.push({"title": "Name=" + item.Title + ", "lat": "" + item.Latitude + "", "lng": "" + item.Longitude + "" });
});
```

Then it will pass to below javascript (Define this javascript below the above javascript in ajax process javascript)

```
function initialize() {       
    var icon = {
        url: '../../Content/Images/redpin.png'
        //url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png'
    };    

    var mapCentre;    

        //Choose some default options
        var mapOptions = {
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.415158, 73.100825),
            //center: myLatlng,
            center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(22.415158, 73.100825), // default to London
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        };       

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var imagee = markers[i];          
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);            
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng));
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: markers[i].title
        });

        (function (marker, data) {
            // Attaching a click event to the current marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.discription);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); 

}
```

Comment: Hello  have replaced my code with yours but the map doesn't center. EDIT: if theres only one marker it works.

Comment: map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng)); this setting map to center please check it carefully